# Got bib file with entry types not recognized by amsrefs

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, amsrefs

From somebody else I received a bib file with the bibliography I have to use. I also have to use `IEEEtran` for the bibliography style. I know it has been used with it and with amsrefs before. For me, it produces errors.

Bibtex only issues warnings:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit)
```

....

```
Warning--entry type for "OpenMP" isn't style-file defined
--line 18 of file parallel.bib
Warning--entry type for "OmpSs17" isn't style-file defined
--line 97 of file parallel.bib
```

....

```
Warning--to sort, need author or key in OpenMP
Warning--missing date in OpenMP
(There were 4 warnings)
```

LaTeX-ing produces errors on these, and on other entries too:

```
! Package amsrefs Error: Undefined entry type: .

See the amsrefs package documentation for explanation.
 ...                                              

l.5 \bib{OpenMP}{}
                  {
? 

Package amsrefs Warning: No authors, editors or translators on input line 9.
```

...

```
! Package amsrefs Error: Undefined entry type: booklet.

See the amsrefs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.362 \bib{STFC17}{booklet}
                           {
?
```

and several others.

Some of the problematic entries in that bib file:

```
@STANDARD{OpenMP,
  title = {{OpenMP 4.5 Specifications}},
  url   = {http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf},
  note  = {{A}ccessed on Oct~13, 2017}
},

@INBOOK{Chamberlain15,
  author    = {Bradford L.~Chamberlain},
  editor    = {Pavan Balaji},
  title     = {Programming Models for Parallel Computing},
  chapter   = {Chapel},
  publisher = {{MIT} Press},
  year      = {2015},
  month     = nov,
}
```

My questions: concerning bibtex warning `to sort, need author or key` - obviously there are types of entries without authors. But what is `key`?

Concerning the rest - clearly there are entry types like `booklet` or `inbook` defined somewhere. How to search for such things?

Fulfilling request for an example, here it is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

Sample citations: \cites{OpenMP,Chamberlain15}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,example}

\end{document}
```

Here the file `example.bib` is exactly as reproduced above, the `bibtex` log is

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "example"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\me\Desktop\example

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: example.aux
The style file: amsrn.bst
Database file #1: IEEEabrv.bib
Database file #2: example.bib
Warning--entry type for "OpenMP" isn't style-file defined
--line 1 of file example.bib
Warning--to sort, need author or key in OpenMP
Warning--missing date in OpenMP
(There were 3 warnings)
```

and the pdflatex log is

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "example.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\me\Desktop\example

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(example.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsrefs\amsrefs.sty"
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty")
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsrefs\pcatcode.sty"
) ("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsrefs\ifoption.st
y")
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsrefs\rkeyval.sty")
 ("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsrefs\textcmds.sty
")
("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsrefs\mathscinet.st
y")) (example.aux) (example.bbl

! Package amsrefs Error: Undefined entry type: .

See the amsrefs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \bib{OpenMP}{}
                  {
? 

Package amsrefs Warning: No authors, editors or translators on input line 9.


! Package amsrefs Error: Undefined entry type: inbook.

See the amsrefs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \bib{Chamberlain15}{inbook}
                                {
? 
) [1{C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(example.aux) )<C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.
9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/M
iKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti8.pfb>
Output written on example.pdf (1 page, 50285 bytes).
SyncTeX written on example.synctex.
Transcript written on example.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 1)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you please make a small example with the offending entries and also a small LaTeX sample file?

Comment: @egreg did it. Should think of it myself, actually...

Comment: (don't know how to do it in one file, sorry)

Comment: For a starter: you can't use `IEEEtran` as a style for `amsrefs`.

Comment: `@STANDARD` seems to be a type which is used  internally in jabref. Upon exporting it should have been replaced with something that really exists, for example `@misc` or `@TechReport`

Comment: @egreg The only thing I know that in this form it has been successfully used by somebody.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In your case it doesn't work, unless you define yourself the requested entry types; not something I'd do. If you want to use `amsrefs` (I know of no real reason for), you can also change the unknown entries to known ones.

Comment: @egreg Many thanks for the answer. Seems like `IEEEtran` is more a must than `amsrefs`, I've just switched it off and everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `amsrefs` with the `IEEEtran` style. Just omit `\usepackage{amsrefs}` and the specific commands.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@STANDARD{OpenMP,
  institution = {{OpenMP}},
  title  = {{OpenMP 4.5 Specifications}},
  url    = {http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf},
  note   = {{A}ccessed on Oct~13, 2017}
},

@INBOOK{Chamberlain15,
  author    = {Bradford L.~Chamberlain},
  editor    = {Pavan Balaji},
  title     = {Programming Models for Parallel Computing},
  chapter   = {Chapel},
  publisher = {{MIT} Press},
  year      = {2015},
  month     = nov,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Sample citations: \cite{OpenMP} \cite{Chamberlain15}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Here I used `\jobname` as the name of the bib database, but it's just to make the example self-contained. Note that a `@STANDARD` entry needs an `institution` field.

[image]

To be more precise: `amsrefs` ignores `\bibliographystyle` commands in the document and uses its own style (`amsrn`). Such a style doesn't know the same entries as `IEEEtran`, in particular `@STANDARD` or `@BOOKLET`.